# Jupyter notebook command is recognized in command line but does not run and freezes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, localhost, port, jupyter

I have been using jupyter notebook for over a year without any problems but recently it decided to stop working randomly. Jupyter notebook command does not give an error but does not do anything too! . the command prompt freezes after that[image: this is the command promt screenshot after i run the command]

Comment: How did you install it? Do you have an Anaconda Distribution or you installed python from scratch?

Comment: i installed it directly using pip

Comment: also installed python directly. never been an anaconda user

Comment: Have you tried to type where jupyter in the console and try to start it from the .exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this. Go to the command window and type following:

```
py -m notebook
```

[image]

Hope that works.Thanks.